# Multiple windows and different views XIB applescript xcode

Tags: xcode, user-interface, storyboard, applescript, xib

I dont really know the terminology for this, but how do you add actions and popover windows in and XIB file? Example: http://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaQ6L3vezqkYzVjVmU1dUtrRHM

I would also like it to be able to display different "pages" on the same window based on buttons. Example: image 1: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaQ6L3vezqkMkV6YW03cTNaSkU
image 2: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzaQ6L3vezqkdTRSTHdVRWNxZWc

On this app, I really like the UI. Hopefully I can make my app look simmalar.

Comment: Show what you've coded already. Your question is like: give me a detailed tutorial (and code) on how to do that. Show your approach, show what you tried.

Comment: @Pat_Morita I don't have code for this, I was wondering how I could do this this since I am unable to use storyboards.

Comment: This is like "Hey, i want to build a skyscraper. I didn't yet start with anything. But i want to know how i can do it." Questions like this will in most of the cases get you NO ANSWER here and on top - some people will downvote them. Nobody wants to wrap up all the knowledge for you you'll need to do that. The best advice we can give you is to start with tutorials and start to build your applications. Once your stuck ask a detailed question like "Hey i cannot fit the brick in my first wall - what am i doing wrong?" and show the code of your first wall - this is the best way to receive answers.